# Trying to install Spek, but cannot understand the error

Tags: apt, package-management

I am new to Linux and I have been trying to install [Spek](http://spek.cc/) but i keep getting this error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libavcodec >= 53.25 libavformat >= 53.17 libavutil >= 51.17) were not met:

No package 'libavcodec' found
No package 'libavformat' found
No package 'libavutil' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables FFMPEG_CFLAGS
and FFMPEG_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I actually have the most recent versions of the mentioned packages.

```
libavcodec58/focal,now 7:4.2.2-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libavformat58/focal,now 7:4.2.2-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libavutil56/focal,now 7:4.2.2-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Can someone help me how to get through the installation or am I missing something?

Comment: How exactly did you (try to) install Spek? Did you download the `tar.gz` file and run `.configure`,  etc.?

Comment: Spek was dropped from Debian in 2019, and dropped from Ubuntu after 19.10. It seems abandoned upstream for many years. It seems like a poor candidate to install in a 20.04 system. If you really want it, try installing on an Ubuntu 18.04 system (try it in a VM).

Comment: When you see messages like this when building software on a Debian/Ubuntu system, they almost always correspond to the `-dev` packages i.e. `libavcodec-dev`, `libavformat-dev`, `libavutil-dev` rather than the runtime library packages like `libavcodec58`

Comment: @Jos, Yes, I did exactly that. It's a **tar.xz archive**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you may have your answers by now.
Since I had some issue linked to installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I post my full answer.

Get sudo rights and make sure you have install all libraries dependencies :

```
sudo -i
apt-get install -y intltool libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libwxgtk3*-dev
```

Download from git the last version of Spek (0.8.3):

```
cd /usr/src
git clone git://github.com/alexkay/
```

Install Spek :

```
cd spek
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install

exit
```